# Far Manager Access denied prompt on file search on Windows

Tags: windows, far-manager

Is there a way to configure Far Manager on Windows to avoid getting "Access denied" / "Additional privileges required" message every time when I start it and run file search through the disk except making it run as Administrator ?

When it comes to to the System Volume Information it privileges are not enough for the user, but I can click "Don't ask again in current session" and continue running without this prompt.

Is there any way to configure it to avoid getting this message?

Comment: If you're searching by file-name, there are far better products for that, for example [voidtools Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/).

Comment: @harrymc, I search to put the results on the panel and handle them in a bunch of operations and I am used to Far Manager for everyday file management operations, so no point to use another tool for one specific operation.

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but you can also in Everything do your search, then press Ctrl+A to select all the results and Ctrl+C to copy all their paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deactivate `Request administrator rights` » `For reading` under `Options` » `System settings`.

```
   ╔═══════════════ System settings ════════════════╗
   ║ [x] Delete to Recycle Bin                      ║
   ║ [x] Use system copy routine                    ║
   ║ [x] Copy files opened for writing              ║
   ║ [x] Scan symbolic links                        ║
   ║ [x] Save commands history                      ║
   ║ [x] Save folders history                       ║
   ║ [x] Save view and edit history                 ║
   ║ [x] Use Windows registered types               ║
   ║ [ ] Automatic update of environment variables  ║
   ║ Request administrator rights:                  ║
   ║     [x] For modification                       ║
   ║     [ ] For reading                            ║
   ║     [x] Use additional privileges              ║
   ║ Sorting collation:  linguistic           ↓     ║
   ║     [x] Treat digits as numbers                ║
   ║     [ ] Case sensitive                         ║
   ║ [ ] Auto save setup                            ║
   ╟────────────────────────────────────────────────╢
   ║               { OK } [ Cancel ]                ║
   ╚════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

```
Request administrator rights
The current user might not always has the required rights to work with certain file system objects. Far allows to retry the operation using the privileged account.
Available options:
- for modification: allow requesting rights for operations that change the state of the file system (e.g. file or directory creation/modification/deletion)
- for read: allow requesting rights for operations that do not change the state of the file system (e.g. reading files or listing directories).
- use additional privileges: attempt accessing all files bypassing Access Control Lists. Use with caution.
```

---

As an alternative you could create a filter that excludes the folders that keep bugging you ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70292536/how-to-skip-searching-directory-by-mask-in-far-manager ) - I haven't tested this but should work.

---

I found the solution by searching in the source code, relevant files:
[elevation.cpp](https://github.com/FarGroup/FarManager/blob/7aec8687eb2f6f1363954651bf32520e66f1a171/far/elevation.cpp#L495) and
[config.cpp](https://github.com/FarGroup/FarManager/blob/7aec8687eb2f6f1363954651bf32520e66f1a171/far/config.cpp#L194-L196)

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer and especially for the way to find it, referencing to the source code. I would consider this code as another exemplar of good C++ code.